# read file content and print only some lines

Tags: php, arrays, file

i have a text file with several content from emails (>20) like this:

```
Von: xx@hsu-xxs.de
Betreff: test
Datum: 13. Juni 2018 um 06:30:10 MESZ
An: xx@xxs.net
Antwort an: xx@hsu-xxs.de

Header
------------------------------

(content)
(content)

(content) 

--
footer
```

i load this file at the moment with this:

```
$file_handle = fopen($file, 'r');

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

  $line = fgets($file_handle);
  (do something ....)

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

my problem is - how can i only read the content of this file? the rest isn't important!
any ideas how to solve this problem?

thanks for help

Andreas

Comment: You might loop through the files and capture the content between the hyphens or perhaps use a pattern to get the matches like `Von:\h+.*(?:\R+(?!Von:\h+|-{2,}).*)*\R+-{2,}\R\K(?:\R(?!--).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/QcTfw6/1

Comment: Is the lines there or is that your way of presenting the content?

Comment: great! that was what I'm looking for. The Site to test/develop regex I doesn't know. Great Tipp from you. Thanks for that!!!